# Exclude an RGB color from a set

Tags: clustering, image-processing

This question has originally been posted on the math stack exchange, but these guys redirected me to you.

Find it at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566065/exclude-an-rgb-color-from-a-set

-- Here's the question again --

I'm currently implementing an algorithm to split an image into smaller chunks, based on straight line separators.

Here's the image I'm processing. It's very small, so you may want to save it and enlarge.

[image: The sample image with three zones]

If you look at this image, you can clearly see 3 different zones. But because I used JPG compression, the separator lines have variable pixel colours.

With the adequate colour difference threshold, it's easy to find these separators (although probably not the best way, now that I rethink about it). Here below are 10 identified separators, or more specifically the average RGB colour of the pixels they contain.

```
# the three big horizontal separators
row 1 : (64, 43, 32)
row 5 : (60, 46, 29)
row 10: (53, 46, 46)

# now if you use these horizontal lines to split the image,
# you still have two images (do not include the horiz. separators)

# the top one contains three vertical separators
col 1 : (54, 45, 42)
col 8 : (152, 124, 81)
col 10: (43, 49, 43)

# and the bottom contains four
col 1 : (53, 48, 36)
col 5 : (53, 50, 30)
col 6 : (52, 46, 32)
col 10: (43, 52, 45)
```

As we can see, one of these color average stands out. And as you may see on the picture, it's not really a separator, but only a column of three pixels alike.

**I need to discard this fake separator from the set**, but I'm having a rough time figuring out an algorithm for this. Initially I'd base this on a standard deviation, removing the ones that are too far away. I don't want to do an average here, as there could be few separators in some cases, and it may lead to false positives.

But I'm lacking mathematical education here. How can I do that on vectors, can anyone provide a working (or better) solution?

Comment: Will all the separators always be approximately the same color? Also, will the separators always be connected to each other?

Comment: Yes, the separators are expected to have the same color (modulo the jpeg compression). And yes, they will be connected to each other, meaning that each sub-image is a closed rectangle. However, there may be no border around the image, nor do I know where a separator starts.

Comment: Two more question, I think I have a past solution I can share. If the separators were all one color would you expect this to be the largest contiguous clump of color? Would you expect the separator color to be the most common color in the image?

Comment: It is very likely, but the other colors may be close. One of the target images is http://24.media.tumblr.com/7d152fc9d14e12bcc5cf3b31fde4a438/tumblr_moyaecBwBq1rlb38jo1_1280.jpg I'd be very interested in seeing your solution anyway :) More sample images here: http://howtotheapp.tumblr.com/

Comment: I keep thinking of things that can go wrong with my original idea, but I have a new one. Can you give code for exactly how you detected the separators?

Comment: This is what I have so far: https://github.com/aspyct/splimage/blob/master/splimage.py but I will probably try to find a better way to identify separators, probably by analyzing each line and doing some clustering. I'm totally open to suggestions here.

Comment: _Totally_ Open? I came up with a pretty weird path finding approach that works with the smaller image. I don't think it will be of practical use for the larger images because it is too slow. It may give you some ideas. The worry I have with the clustering is that it is not necessarily true that the largest cluster corresponds to the separators, so we would need some other metric to decide this (ideas?). Also, you at first appear to have a perfect case for k-means clustering because there are only two categories (separator or not) but it did not work well when I tried to do it.